# Applications of computer science in biology

Tags: reference-request, application-of-theory, bioinformatics

Is there a survey or tutorial article which talks about application of theoretical computer science to emerging fields of applications of computer science in biology, bioinformatics and nanotechnology?

Are there any problems from these fields that are unsolved and are of intrinsic merit to theoretical computer science?

Are there any algorithms that are already useful or potentially useful in current or future real-world applications and products in these fields? Is there any article which talks about real-world applications and products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite a few programs have resulted from the application of notions from theoretical computer science or mathematics to problems in biology. This includes [phylogeny](http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/software.html), [sequence alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequence_alignment_software), and genome rearrangement (see [this](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=11899), chapter 15) software. But you may be asking too many or too unfocused questions at once.

Answer (score 3):

> What are some of the major open issues of theoretical computer science applied to biology?

Here is a nice presentation, [Open questions in bioinformatics and computational biology from an evolutionary and molecular biology perspective](http://stajichlab.fungalgenomes.org/presentations/2009-11-16_UCR_CompSci.pdf), given in 2009 by Jason Stajich.